# Get Json Data From Asp.Net Webmethod and Consume in angularJS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, webmethod

Can any one guide me how to get json data from asp.net webmethod, and consume it in angularJS.

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http) { 
    try { 
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'ProblemList.aspx/GetProblemList' })
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
    alert(data); }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
    }); 
    } catch (e) { 
    throw e; 
    }
```

Comment: app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http) {

                    try {

                         $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'ProblemList.aspx/GetProblemList' }).

                         success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                             alert(data);
                         }).
                         error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                         });
                    } catch (e) {
                        throw e;
                    }

Comment: does it hit the function when you put a breakpoint, if not post your method too.

Comment: No, its not hitting the function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, I tried many different ways, this is the way I found it works... ( I think the tricks is a combination of the header config, and the json parameter with "data : {}", I am not sure but It was really tricky )

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestAngular.aspx.cs" Inherits="COEWebApp.NCoe.Employees.TestAngular" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">

  <div ng-controller="MyController" >
    <button ng-click="myData.doClick(item, $event)">Send AJAX Request</button>
    <br/>
    Data from server: {{myData.fromServer}}
  </div>

  <script>
      angular.module("myapp", [])
          .controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {
              $scope.myData = {};
              $scope.myData.doClick = function (item, event) {

                  $http.post('TestAngular.aspx/GetEmployees', { data: {} })
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.myData.fromServer = data.d;
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.status = status;
                    });

              }


          }).config(function ($httpProvider) {

              $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};

              $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

          });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And on the same aspx page on the codebehid this is the simple code...

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetEmployees()
{
  return "OK-test";
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me, I was not passing the second parameter "{ data: {} }"

Answer (score 1):

Here, Simple `Angularjs Ajax Call` to `WebMethod` and get response

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyController" >

  <div ng-click="getData()">GetData</div> <br />     
  {{showData}}
</div>    
_____________________________________________________
<script>
    var test = angular.module("myapp", []);
    test.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.getData = {};
            $scope.getData = function () {

                try {
                    // Call to Web Method
                    var httpRequest = $http({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "AjaxCall.aspx/test",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {},      //use if want send parameter ::  data: {id:1},
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        }
                    });

                    // if success 
                    httpRequest.success(function (data, status) {
                        $scope.showData = data.d;
                        console.log(JSON.parse(data.d));  // conversion string to json format
                    });

                    // if fail
                    httpRequest.error(function (data, status) {
                        $scope.status = status;
                        console.log(status);
                    });
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log(e + " Some Error");
                }

            };
        });
</script>
```

Code behind page:

```
// AjaxCall.aspx.cs file
[WebMethod]
public static string test()  // if parameterized call :: test(string id)
{
    return "succeed";
}
```