# Getting JSON From .NET Webmethod, for use in ng-repeat

Tags: .net, json, angularjs, webmethod

Okay, so I've searched around far and wide and gotten some help. Not the least from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657665/1223463

But here's where I stand:

I get the data back from the Webmethod, and am able to display it with a simple `{{data}}` on the page. However, nothing displays when I try to loop through the data (it consists of two JSON objects), and referencing their data keys.

Javascript:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
            .controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {

                $scope.data = [];
                $scope.getData = function (item, event) {
                    $http.post('NGTest.aspx/GetGroups', { data: {} })
                        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            $scope.data = data.d;
                        });
                };

        }).config(function ($httpProvider) {

                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};

                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            });
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="MyController" >
        <button ng-click="getData(item, $event)">Get data</button>
        <br/>

        {{data}}

        <div ng-repeat="d in data">
            {{d.ID}} a row
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Code behind:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string GetGroups()
    {
        return @"[{
            'ID': 1568,
                'Orgno': '282-1'
        }, {
            'ID': 1569,
                'Orgno': '8925-2'
        }]";
    }
```

So, when I press the button, I get the data displayed as: `[{ 'ID': 1568, 'Orgno': '282-1' }, { 'ID': 1569, 'Orgno': '8925-2' }]` plain and simple. But the ng-repeat part yields no code.

Here's a fiddle with seemingly the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/eurythmech/t9jzbm06/

The one thing I can see is different between them is that in the fiddle, the JSON data is supplied without quotes surrounding it.

Is this what I need to fix, somehow? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your data are returned as a string and not as an object. You can add an eval in your $http call :

```
$scope.getData = function (item, event) {
   $http.post('NGTest.aspx/GetGroups', { data: {} })
   .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       $scope.data = eval(data.d);
   });
};
```

A better way would be to return an Array of objects in your GetGroups method, so ASP.NET will serialize it for you. More infos right there [WebMethod returning JSON but the response obj in my $.ajax() callback is only a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228648/webmethod-returning-json-but-the-response-obj-in-my-ajax-callback-is-only-a)

One more thing, as you said, JSON must use double quotes for strings (check http://www.json.org/ )

Comment: Thank you! The eval() bit works brilliantly, but maybe I'll heed your suggestion and do it the better way in the end. (The actual code I intended to use .NET's JavaScriptSerializer, as I wasn't aware that I could pull it off without it :)