# How to pass or fetch data from AngularJS to Aspx using WebMethod?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I have to fetch a string from `aspx` to `angularJS` and display it. But I am not getting any response or it might be `AngularJS` is not triggering the method.
Here is my `Angular Controller`

```
controller('ReadTextController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

        $scope.showData = function () {
            $http.post('KeyPhraseGroup.aspx/GetEmployees', { data: {} })  
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
    $scope.result = data.d;  
})  
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
    $scope.status = status;  
});  
}  
});
```

And here is my `aspx`method

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetEmployees()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

I am triggering the `showData()` method of the `AngularJS` controller in my `html` page but not getting the `string` fetched.

**Changed Explanation**

I am getting value as `undefined`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Json Data From Asp.Net Webmethod and Consume in angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076175/get-json-data-from-asp-net-webmethod-and-consume-in-angularjs)

Comment: I am doing the same but getting value as `undefined`

Comment: Do you mean `aspx` page when you refer to `html` page?

Comment: Ya I mean `aspx` page