# Fetching string data from aspx to angularjs is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, json

I am trying to fetch a string from `aspx` backend to `AngularJS` using `http post` but it is returning undefined.
Here is my code

```
<body data-ng-app="myapp">
<div data-ng-controller="MyController" >
    <button data-ng-click="myData.doClick(item, $event)">Send AJAX Request</button>
    <br/>
    Data from server: {{myData.fromServer}}
  </div>
<script>
      angular.module("myapp", [])
          .controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {
              $scope.myData = {};
              $scope.myData.doClick = function (item, event) {
              $http.post('KeyPhraseGroup.aspx/GetEmployees', { data: {} })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.myData.fromServer = data.d;
                    console.log($scope.myData.fromServer);
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.status = status;
                });
           }
      }).config(function ($httpProvider) {
          $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
          $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
      });
```

And below is my `c#` method

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetEmployees()
    {
        return "OK-test";
    }
```

Reference [Get Json Data From Asp.Net Webmethod and Consume in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076175/get-json-data-from-asp-net-webmethod-and-consume-in-angularjs)

Comment: Did you check your `Devtools => network` panel to ensure the call went fine and returned some data?

Comment: @David the call went fine return url is something like this "http://localhost:35633/Account/Login?ReturnUrl="%"2FKeyPhraseGroup.aspx"%"2FGetEmployees"

Comment: But, it has to return `OK-test` in your case right?

Comment: Ya It should return OK-test but its returning undefined